# SwiftUI Button to Selector action

Tags: appkit, swiftui

I need to have a SwiftUI button perform an Objective-C selector on the currently focused component. The following works:

```swift
let button = Button(action: {
  let command = #selector(NSStandardKeyBindingResponding.selectAll(_:))
   NSApplication.shared.currentEvent?.window?.firstResponder?.doCommand(by: command)
}, label: { Text("Select All") })
```

…but it is obviously really ugly. SwiftUI has a `Command` struct that can wrap a `Selector`, but it isn't clear how the selector can actually be invoked once the command is created.

What is the recommended way to issue an arbitrary `Command` when a button is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dispatch an action along the responder chain, you can use the [`-[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428509-sendaction) method, passing `nil` for the target.

You'd do this if you want to work with the AppKit responder chain, which might include your SwiftUI `NSHostingView` along with the rest of the responder chain (its superviews, and window, and so on). In theory if you wanted to handle a selector-based action from SwiftUI content, you can use the [`onCommand`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3340134-oncommand) modifier to recognize a `Command` wrapping that selector. However, your `NSHostingView` needs to be in the AppKit responder chain, and the `onCommand` SwiftUI view needs to be focused (or an ancestor of the focused view) for the command to be recognized. The main benefit to this is that you can also handle menubar actions using the exact same code, since menubar actions usually dispatch through the responder chain.

If you're trying to modify state related to some other SwiftUI view, it might be more straightforward to pass a `Binding` or a closure parameter to your view struct as an argument to its initializer. For example, you could maintain some state somewhere else (i.e. "the set of selected objects") and then pass a closure to the button that modifies the state ("put every object in the set of selected objects") without having to directly teach the button about that state.

Comment: Does this actually work in your experience? Even with standard commands like `MyFocsedView().onCommand(Command.copy) { print("copy!") }`, the command is never actually performed (at least, as of beta3).

Comment: I've tried different ways to test the modifier onCommand(_:perform:) but it doesn't get called! I will be grateful to have an example of usage of it! :)

Comment: @Jeff the `onCommand` modifier link is broken. Has that been removed from SwiftUI?

Comment: @DuncanC appears the URL has been updated to [oncommand(_:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/oncommand(_:perform:)/)