# Can you tie a SwiftUI Mac app's menu item to the front window like you can in AppKit

Tags: macos, swiftui, menuitem, first-responder

In AppKit, you can set up a menu item so that it invokes a selector in the first responder. If memory serves, you do that by setting its target to nil, and then the system walks the responder chain, looking for a responder that implements that selector. If it finds one, it enables the menu item and links it to the responder. If not, it disables the menu item.

I'd like to add a menu item that acts on the front-most window (Swapping between pairs of TextFields.) If the front-most window supports the menu item, I'd like it to be enabled, and disabled if not.

In AppKit, I'd give the menu item a selector that I implemented one of the window's responders. (Maybe the window controller, maybe the view controller. I'd have to decide what made the most sense.)

How would I achieve that in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56875123/5133585)

Comment: @Sweeper the link you posted gives some hints on how to "catch" the selector from SwiftUI. How do I set up a menu command to send a selector to the responder chain?

Comment: That's where you need to use AppKit, to add the SwiftUI view into the responder chain. e.g. use a `NSHostingView` as the linked post says. SwiftUI itself is separate from the responder chain. There might b a pure SwiftUI way to do this, without involving the responder chain, but if you *do* want to use the responder chain, you need AppKit.